# Does TensorFlow's automatic device placement handles the multi-GPU case?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I know that with TensorFlow it is possible to manually control where we declare variables (e.g.: half of a neural network on a GPU and the rest of it on another GPU).

Despite it is sure that we can place variables on multiple GPU **manually**, could they be placed **automatically** on those multiple GPUs, such as using automatic variable placement? TensorFlow's documentation seems to never mention explicitly whether or not the automatic device placement handles multi-GPU cases.

*For example*, let's say that I build a model with Keras with the TensorFlow backend. If the model does not fit all inside the first GPU because it is too big, will TensorFlow automatically use the second GPU (and potentially more GPUs) for declaring the neural network's variables?

Thanks.

Comment: no, TensorFlow tries to run everything it can on gpu:0 if present

Comment: Thanks a lot. You could answer the question, and I would accept it as the best answer. I would like to have more details about the "except integer valued ops" if you have examples in mind.

Comment: I would also be interested in knowing potential performance drawbacks of using multiple GPUs. Should I expect performances to drop a lot just because of such a split of the neural network? To me, it seems like not, thought I am not sure since it would still need to transfer the output of one tensor at the midst of the forward pass, and to do this again for the backward pass during training in the case of a CNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ref the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)

If you have more than one GPU in your system, the GPU with the lowest ID will be selected by default. If you would like to run on a different GPU, you will need to specify the preference explicitly:

```
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/gpu:2'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

Comment: I already read that. The title just above your excerpt says `Using a single GPU on a multi-GPU system`, which mislead me into thinking it was not talking about the automatic placement when talking about the default behavior. I hoped the default behavior was different... well, not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[No, you are responsible for device placement:](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_a_single_gpu_on_a_multi-gpu_system)

> If you have more than one GPU in your system, the GPU with the lowest
> ID will be selected by default.

I assume that this is done because moving data from GPU to another one might be costly and the system does not really knows in which case it is justifiable to move the data.